# How to confirm and call function with onclick

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

Can I call JavaScript function with `return confirm();` in HTML onclick event or do I need to do function which contains confirmation and call to another function?

```html
<button onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?'); saveandsubmit(event);"></button>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Add if condition

```
<button onclick="if(confirm('Are you sure?')) saveandsubmit(event);"></button>
```

OR

```
<button onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')?saveandsubmit(event):'';"></button>
```

Answer (score 4):

Try below :

```
<button onclick="confirm('Are you sure ?') && saveAndSubmit(event)">Button</button>


function saveAndSubmit(event){
    alert('saveAndSubmit called !');
}
```

JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/nikdtu/cyt955bp/