# close the window after submit the form jsp

Tags: javascript, jsp, struts2

I have a pop-up form which used to enter some user values.There is a button called 'submit' to submit the form data and after window should be close itself. I have tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32394684/how-to-confirm-and-call-function-with-onclick), but it didn't work. Always window close function worked first and submit function didn't work.

Here I have attached my code sample on jsp
`<s:submit value="Reject" cssClass="btn2" onclick="if(reject()) {closeWindow();}" />`

```
function reject(){       
 document.forms[0].action = "url",
 document.forms[0].submit();

 return true;
}
function closeWindow(){
        window.close();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to set `onSubmit` handler to the form and close the window there?

Comment: yes, I tried that. But window.close() function always worked before form submit.